# How to make some fields not updatable once saved in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have build a schema as follows:

```
const UserInfoSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    displayName: { type: String, required: true },
    profilePic: {
        filename: {type: String},
        url: {type: String}
    },
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
})
```

What I need here is once the fields such as email, username and userId are saved, should not be modified. Is there anything pre-build in mongoose for this kind of feature?

I have done some research on `schema.pre('update', (next) => {})`, but got nothing really useful/don't know if one can use for the mentioned feature. Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know your case but even the owner still can not edit their email ?

Comment: @thelonglqd let's not go deep into the functionality of my app. I think the answer would not have any relevancy with what features I am giving to users in my app.

Comment: I don't think there is. For example, there are various ways to update a document which does not always call the `pre` hook. Anyways, can't you just ensure that you only update the fields you want in your code e.g. using `$set`? That would be a good [option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#options) e.g. `freeze` to have in the schema though.

Comment: @Mikey I have ensured the updates won't get the data as you said. But, I was curious whether mongoose/mongodb would provide such features. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier way
when you save the Schema, you can set the field as immutable, like this

```
const UserInfoSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, immutable:true },
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, immutable:true },
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', immutable:true},
    displayName: { type: String, required: true },
    profilePic: {
        filename: {type: String},
        url: {type: String}
    },
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
})
```

it won't throw any error, if you want it you should check it elsewhere, but when you try to modify the immutable fields, it wont be changed at all

Answer (score 0):

```
for(const key in userUpdates) {
    switch(key)  { 
        case 'username':
        case 'email':
            throw new Error('These field/s cannot be changed anymore');
    }
}
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, userUpdates, { new: true, runValidators: true });
```